# "a rebound in the economy" VS "a bounce in the economy"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

> 1. Despite a **rebound** in the economy, the fundamentals of many firms have not take a turn for the better.
> 2. Despite a **bounce** in the economy, the fundamentals of many firms have not take a turn for the better.

If I want to express that the economy recovers from a recession, which word should I choose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two nouns say much the same thing but there is a distinction between their implied extent of the economic recovery being referred to.

Objects that **bounce** do not rise very far before they start falling again. The word suggests a temporary, moderate movement.

**Rebound**, on the other hand, suggests a steadier, more positive ascent.

Depending on your judgement of the improvement that you are describing, you can opt for the lesser **bounce** or the stronger **rebound**.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rebound
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bounce

Comment: I think it might be more accurate to say ***rebound*** can often imply *[permanently] rise back up to the **normal** level*, as opposed to ***bounce*** implying *[temporarily] oscillate between an unsustainable high level and a "base" level, with progressively smaller peaks, before settling at the lower level*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I wish I'd worded it that way

Comment: I bet someone else here could express exactly the distinction I was making there in far less words, but I'm glad you see it the same way. If two native speakers agree on a subtle distinction like this, it pretty much proves there's at least *some* truth to the perspective! Actually, I just remembered that in financial jargon, a ***bounce*** is sometimes explicitly referenced as a ***dead cat bounce*** (in my experience, dead cats don't bounce very high, or for long, and they quickly settle to the lowest point in the oscillation! :)

Comment: A bounce is a sudden rise in value of a share or currency in a fluctuating market. Siemens shares bounced yesterday on news of their deal with Toyota. A rebound is a recovery and a longer-term trend. Is the US economy really on the rebound after years of stagnation. We'll be with you right after the break...

Comment: There's also the verbal phrase *bounce back* which is synonymous with the verb *rebound*. Just to make it more confusing.